# How to print the data vertically?

Tags: c

In this code, I used char pointer variables and printed them because I want to save the data using pointers but printing should be vertically o variables instead of printing horizontally. I don't know how to do it?

**Given output**

```
Name: FirstSecondThirdFour
DOB: FirstSecondThirdFour
ID: FirstSecondThirdFour
Phone: FirstSecondThirdFour
```

**Expected output**

```
Name: First
DOB: Second
ID: Third
Phone: Four
```

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  int i;
  char *one = "First", *two = "Second", *three = "Third", *four = "Four";
  char *listing[] = {"Name", "DOB", "ID", "Phone"};

  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf("%s: %s%s%s%s\n", listing[i], one, two, three, four);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `switch`.

```
int main(){
  int i;
  char *listing[] = {"Name", "DOB", "ID", "Phone"};

  for(i=0; i<4; i++){

    char *data = "";
    switch(i) {
      case 0: data = "first";
      case 1: data = "second";
      case 2 data = "third";
      case 3: data = "fourth";
    }

    printf("%s: %s%s\n", listing[i], data);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Or you can map index to string as below

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  int i;
  char *mapper[] = {"First", "Second", "Third", "Four"};
  char *listing[] = {"Name", "DOB", "ID", "Phone"};

  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf("%s: %s%s\n", listing[i], mapper[i]);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

or maintain the records using structures as below.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

typdef struct {
   char *data;
   char *pos;
} List;

int main(){
  int i;
  List listing[] = {{"Name", "First"}, {"DOB, "Second"}, {"ID", "Third"}, {"phone", "Four"};


  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf("%s: %s%s\n", listing[i].data, listing[i].pos);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the variables are more than one. You used just one variable that is data.

Comment: I am basically getting data from file and divided the data one by one. That's why I used multiple variables to make you understand.

Comment: @Dazthaak Perhaps what you need is to use arrays (possibly dynamically allocated) of structures?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude what if I get this data from a file and divided one by one in multiple variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your string variables as their names (eg. `char *one`, `char *two`), you can push them into a list - then your code will something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define STRING_LEN 200

int main(){
  int i;
  char *one = "First", *two = "Second", *three = "Third", *four = "Four";
  char *listing[] = {"Name", "DOB", "ID", "Phone"};
  char *strs[] = {one, two, three, four};

  for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf("%s: %s\n", listing[i], strs[i]);
  }   
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you write in comments (information that really should be in the question itself!) what you need to use is arrays of *structures*.

Perhaps something like:

```
struct person
{
    char name[100];
    char dob[20];
    char id[10];
    char phone[20];
};
```

Then just for test:

```
struct person persons[] = {
    { "Jake"  , "2013-06-07", "id-01", "123-456-789" },
    { "Jarren", "2019-10-03", "id-02", "456-789-012" }
};

size_t num_persons = 2;  // Number of persons in the array

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_persons; ++i)
{
    printf("Name   : %s\n", persons[i].name);
    printf("DOB    : %s\n", persons[i].dob);
    printf("ID     : %s\n", persons[i].id);
    printf("Phone  : %s\n", persons[i].phone);
}
```